# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when using malloc function

Tags: c, malloc

The "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error occurs when using the malloc function. I learned that malloc's initialization value is filled with trash memory. Is Segmentation fault error occurring in this part?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int chnum;

char *getstr(void)
{
    char *str1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * chnum);
    printf("Write a string: ");
    gets(str1);
    return str1;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("What is the maximum length of a string? ");
    scanf("%d",chnum);
    char *set = getstr();
    printf("string : %s \n",set);
    free(set);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you address the "trash memory" thing first?

Comment: `scanf("%d",chnum);` -> `scanf("%d", &chnum);` (turn on compiler warnings!).

Comment: `gets(str1);` is likely to cause a buffer overflow. Never use `gets`, it is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) The buffer size is off-by-one too (for the null terminator).

Comment: A better design for your `getstr` function would take the string length as a parameter, instead of relying on a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Casting result of the malloc is considered as a bad practice.
2. Do no use global variables to pass the data between the functions. Use function parameters for it
3. You do not have to `sizeof(char)` as it is by definition 1
4. Always check the result of malloc
5. Do not use `gets` use `fgets` instead
6. Always check the result of scanf.
7. In `scanf` pass the pointer to the object not the object itself.
8. Check result of the function which can fail (`getstr`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getstr(size_t chnum)
{
    char *str1 = malloc(chnum);
    if(str1)
    {
        printf("Write a string: ");
        fgets(str1, chnum, stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return str1;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t chnum;
    printf("What is the maximum length of a string? ");
    if(scanf("%zu", &chnum) == 1)
    {
        printf("\n");
        fgetc(stdin);
        char *str = getstr(chnum);
        if(str) 
        {
            printf("string : %s \n",str);
            free(str);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare chnum in size_t type in your answer and print it in %zu type?
I tried to declare it as an int type and print it as %d, but it doesn't work.